# Referring to Javascript Constants within GWT code

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, jsni

Is there a way using JSNI and JSOT (javascript overlay types) to map a JavaScript constants to a custom java-type?

Example:

I map the Google Map V3 javascript API to GWT and there is the [MapTypeId](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeId) constants. I'd like to refer in my javacode to the TERRAIN constant (which is a javascript string) as a MapTypeId object (which is a POJO and not a java.lang.String). So far, the compiler says it could not map the javascript string to my custom type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only I made it work is to wrap the string constants in a pure javascript object and map it as a dumb overlay-types. The GWT java-to-js compiler then is able to cast that as my strongly-typed MapTypeId.

```
public static native MapTypeId getHybrid() /*-{
        return { value : $wnd.google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID };
    }-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

External scripts are loaded in the HTML host page, which you'll reference in JSNI as `$wnd`. I don't know the Maps API, but I guess `$wnd.MapTypeId` should work.